# How to import PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu command line

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to import a PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu. Everything is installed and updated but the problem still presists, any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Use the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html) or \COPY.

Answer (score 0):

Login to psql terminal by typing this

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Enter this command in the psql terminal, exit and try again.

```
alter role postgres superuser;
```